# Reset list sass/css

Tags: html, css, sass, less, stylesheet

I am trying to reset ul and li to its default behavior via a class, but I am having trouble with that. I have tried using `inherit` and `initial` but that does not work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And so I want to have a class in this case called `.list-unset` that would set the child DOM to browser defaults and not take on `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`.

I have tried:

```
.list-unset {
    ul, li {
        margin: unset;
        padding: unset;
    }
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Use css specificity to your advantage here, that means set the global ul and li at the top of the cascade/CSS and lower create your variations to override that global style; what you're doing is going at it from the other way around which defeats the purpose of the cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'correct' way to reset a `<ul>` element is with [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit):

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.unset, ul.unset > li {
  margin: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="unset">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

However, keep in mind that this value is inherited from its *parent element*. Whatever rules are applied to the parent (if any) will apply to the target. If no rules are set, it will set to the default, as above.

Failing that, you can manually apply the default `<ul>` styles to the target element, ensuring that you apply higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/):

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.unset {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul.unset > li {
  margin: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="unset">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```